# How do i configure nginx to redirect to a url for robots.txt & sitemap.xml

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

I am running nginx 0.6.32 as a proxy front-end for couchdb. I have my robots.txt in the database, reachable as http://www.example.com/prod/_design/mydesign/robots.txt. I also have my sitemap.xml which is dynamically generated, on a similar url.

I have tried the following config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
  if ($request_method = DELETE) {
    return 444;
  }
  if ($request_uri ~* "^/robots.txt") {
    rewrite ^/robots.txt http://www.example.com/prod/_design/mydesign/robots.txt permanent;
  }

  proxy-pass http://localhost:5984;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

This appears to work as a redirect but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Or you can put it simply in its own location -

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /Directory-containing-robots-file/robots.txt;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution, and works perfectly for me.

Comment: When you say `directory-containing-file`, I presume you mean *including* the filename? I tried `alias /www/static;`, with and without trailing slashes, and it failed. When I used `alias /www/static/robots.txt;`, it worked fine.

Comment: John C - No, only the directory. instead of putting `alias /directory;` you can also put `root /opt/directory/;` Hope that helps.

Comment: On my dev site i am using a wildcard in my sites-available to serve up any one of the projects..  can i use this approach to have all my projects use the same robots.txt file?  if so then how?  I tried to follow your directions but the robots.txt file that is within that project is being served

Comment: Thanks! If you need sitemaps (more than one file),
`location /sitemap { root /home/ec2-user/app_directory/public; }`

Comment: So what's the conclusion from all this? You do or don't need an "="? Do alias and root do the same thing or different? You should or should not include 'robots.txt' on the end?

Answer (score 20):

I think you want to setup a location. The key part being the "=" directive.

```
location = /robots.txt {
    alias /your_full_path/robots.txt ;
}
```

(When I didn't include the =, it still went to the default nginx root location)

Setting it like below, would cause all /robots.txt* requests to be read out of /var/foo. So /robots.txt.bing tries reading /var/foo/robots.txt.bing off of disk. The "^~" indicates that it is a regular expression match on the beginning of the request.

```
location ^~ /robots.txt {
    root /var/foo;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

rewrite with http://... is inteded to do the redirect. You are probably looking for:

```
rewrite ^/robots.txt /prod/_design/mydesign/robots.txt last;
```

Comment: needs equals to work:

`location = /sitemap.xml {
 rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?xxxxxxxxx permanent;
}`

Answer (score 3):

This should work also, and *may* perform slightly better.

```
location /robots.txt { alias /var/www/django/mysite/static/robots.txt; }
```

Comment: Why may it perform slightly better?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first parameter is a regular expression so you should probably escape . and match end of line.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/robots\.txt$ /static/robots.txt last;
    ...
}
```

[NginxHttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `robots.txt` is located at `/var/www/mysite/static/robots.txt`, the following worked for me:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    root /var/www/mysite/static/;
}
```