# How do I go straight to template, in Django's urls.py?

Tags: python, django, templates

Instead of going to views.py, I want it to go to to a template, robots.txt.

Comment: The given answer is accurate, although, for something like robots.txt, you may route it at webserver level too. It won't even reach your django app. For `nginx` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3746344/781695, For `apache` : http://serverfault.com/a/213455/84120

Answer (score 276, accepted):

## Django 2+

Note: is valid still as of Django 4+

Use the class based generic views but register with the django 2.0+ pattern.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo.html'))
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf

## Django 1.5+

Use the class based generic views.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo.html')),
)
```

#Django <= 1.4
Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^foo/$',             'direct_to_template', {'template': 'foo_index.html'}),
    (r'^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'foo_detail.html'}),
)
```

Comment: For 1.5+, do we need to do this for every static HTML?

Answer (score 14):

A further update for more recent versions and including mime type from this site:

http://www.techstricks.com/adding-robots-txt-to-your-django-project/

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    #... your project urls
    url(r'^robots.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"), name="robots_file")
]
```