# can i do this in django? admin with pages as models vs cms?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Today I was just in the train and had some spare time to think about django cms and admin.

Can I define pages as models like this:

```
class ArticlePage(models.Model):
  slug = models.TextField()
  content = models.TextField()
  online  = models.BooleanField()
  etc...
```

and then edit this model in django admin? Because, i think, django cms will also work,more or less, in this way, right?

will this be fine?

Where i am stuck is that i dont know how to set dynamic urls for those pages, because i need to touch urls.py for this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can create a view which has a wildcard as the URL. And then have the view lookup the various actually used URLs in the ArticlePage.

```
def pageView(request, url):
    page = ArticlePage.objects.get(slug=url)
    ...
    return page.content
```

With the URLs specified as:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('articles.views',
    (r'^(?P<url>.+?)/$', 'pageView'),
) #Catch all URLs not yet matched and attempt to find them in the database.
```

at the end of your `urls.py`.

And then you can use an HTML editor of some sort to create the actual content and whatnot.

So it is possible. However the question is do you want to?
It is possible to create a few of the pages on a website completely from scratch and storing the HTML in a database. Think small pages which are rarely updated but if updated change rigorously.

However, generally speaking a website has some structure. Something like blog posts, comments, polls, user registration and other interactive pages. Those pages cannot be described in a database field holding HTML.

Although if you do actually manage to do all that then I fear for your sanity because it must have been a painful and awkward road.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**
If you want to show a static HTML only page you normally just refer to them directly from the urls.py. Generally very few HTML is directly stored in databases. Most often you just store data in the database. If HTML is heavily being modified/saved/created/served from the CMS you just store it as an HTML file somewhere on the webserver.

Although one can certainly think of reasons to put HTML pages in the Database there is an equal many reasons as to why you shouldn't. It all comes down to the specifics of the problem. 
E.g. if you allow a user to create a comment with links/boldface/italics etc. you can save the **word** or //word// in the db and parse it every time. Or you can parse it once and just store the HTML in the database so you don't have to parse it every time.

Same goes for larger pages although they generally have too much markup to be hand typed via the CMS every so often.

As for serving an HTML page directly via `urls.py`:

E.g.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo.html')),
)
```

Source: [How do I go straight to template, in Django's urls.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201346/how-do-i-go-straight-to-template-in-djangos-urls-py)

Comment: thanks dude, .. one more question, does django cms store html pages also in db? no, right?

Comment: Normally if you create a small html page you just refer to those via urls.py. I've added an example to the answer.