# ng-include angular with django template system

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I am using Django with angular,

In my angular scope, I have :

```
$scope.templates = [
    { name: 'addSongTemplateAjax', url: "templates/add_song_for_ajax.html"}, 
    { name: '', url: ''}
];
$scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
```

in my html file I have :

```
<div class = "add_song_submit_form" ng-include="template.url">
</div>
```

So, I want load the template add_song_for_ajax.html from the javascript angular side. It's doesn't work. Django throw me an error 404. I know it's logic because We try to find the url in the urls.py ...

So I am sure I have to deal with the settings and urls.py of my application in order to say to django, yes the client can load this file ! But I dont find how.

My template.html I want to load

```
<div class="alert alert-info" style = "margin-bottom:10px!important; margin-top:10px;">The song will be added to the playlist selected <strong>//playlist_selected.fields.name//</strong></div>
<form role = "form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for = "artist_band">Artist / Band</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="artist_band" placeholder = "Enter artist / band">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title">Title / Song name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title / Song name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for = "url">Url</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="url" placeholder = "Url">
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click = "submit_add_song()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your url in single quotes, as per [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
$scope.templates = [
    { name: 'addSongTemplateAjax', url: "'templates/add_song_for_ajax.html'"}, 
    { name: '', url: ''}
];
```

Comment: That's not resolve the problem here ... Its not a problem with quotes, its a problem about routing

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the template in your url list in Django.  See the updated answer in [How do I go straight to template, in Django's urls.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201346/how-do-i-go-straight-to-template-in-djangos-urls-py) for an example and brief explanation.  Depending on what you put in urls.py, you may want to take the "templates/" out of the url in your client-side templates class.

Answer (score 0):

Are those dynamic templates purely just AngularJS or do they need Django's context as well?

---

#### 1. Angular only

If those templates have no need for Django's context or template tags, then you can treat them as static files. And place them inside your STATICFILES directory.

You can then load them in angular by providing angular with the full url to those templates (e.g. the output of `{% static 'templates/add_song_for_ajax.html' %}`).

Angular's AJAX should be able to load those static HTML files with no problem.

The drawback to this solution is that if you change your `STATIC_URL` in your Django settings, you should also change it in your JS.

#### 2. Angular plus Django

If your dynamic templates need Django's context, then you should write those templates as Django templates, write their respective views and configure your `urls.py`.

You can then use your configured urls in your JS to point to those Django URLs.

Don't forget about Django's and AngularJS' conflicting template tags. See [AngularJS with Django - Conflicting template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)?